# SharePoint hosted app - same REST POST fails on-prem works fine on Office 365; error "A relative URI value '' was specified in the payload..."

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-addin

I have issued the same REST POST to add an item to a SharePoint list.  It works fine in Office 365 and I get the following error in on-prem version of SharePoint.  SP1 and OData 3 have been configured correctly (REST GET requests work fine).  I have no idea what this message even means and internet search reveals nothing specific to SharePoint.  Any help would be much appreciated.

The URL (fiddler) looks like the following:
`http://add-in-dd9be1d7d03f28.myaddindomain.com/sites/myteamsite/myappname/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyListName')/items`

This is the full error:

> {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A relative URI value '' was specified in the payload, but no base URI for it was found. If the payload contains a relative URI a base URI must be specified on the reader settings."}}}

Comment: Do you have a custom DNS name for your on-prem environment? It looks like your url format might be different for your on-prem environment. How are you making REST requests here? `RequestExecutor`, jQuery, good old `HttpWebRequest` in C#? The problem is likely in the request headers or payload rather than the URL, can you post the code that generates the request?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...  I created an "on-prem" environment in Azure (following a series of instructions) and my app domain is "testsp2013addins.com"  so the full URL is like the above http://add-in-dd9be1d7d03f28.testsp2013addins.com/...    I am using RequestExecutor cross-domain lib (even though I don't think I need it for the app web).  My code is in TypeScript and I basically just build up the SP.RequestInfo object and pass it like executor.executeAsync(spRequestInfo).   I can try to send a screen shot of the spRequestInfo variable from the debugger if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error etc. I found the problem.  I was posting an item to a SharePoint list and in my code I set defaults for the SharePoint "__metadata" property object.  The problem was setting a default for uri of "" (empty string).  When posting this JSON my SharePoint on-prem installation didn't like this (but was OK in Office 365).  The solution was to not set a default and not post the uri property at all.

```
{
    "Id": -1,
    "Prop1": "data",
    "Prop2": "data",
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.mylistnameListItem",
        "etag": "",
        "id": "",
        "uri": ""  <-- this was the problem line -->
    }
}
```